# Best solution to refresh UI from device in real time in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, usb

I'm currently working on a project. This will be a GUI in WPF/C#.

This GUI consist of an infinite thread that continously reads a device through USB (using a dll) / process the information / updates the UI visual components (labels and LEDs).

I'm having two main problems. The main UI window seems to lose responsiveness when this background thread is active. And also it seems that my app have some memory leaks that causes the GUI to crash (OutOfMemoryException) after some hours.

What would be the best way to update a UI all the time without losing responsiveness and handling this crash? Best practices or some example maybe?

Comment: Show me your example first 

Comment: It's huge. Let me try to summarize it for you.

Comment: BackgroundWorker ReportsProgress

Comment: Thank you. It's good SO etiquette, plus memory leakage can occur in *so* many ways

Comment: Still with the BackgroundWorker and using ReporProgress it gets very unresponsive, I'm refreshing 64 textboxes, processing the values to interpretare some Voltages, Currents and also refreshing some textboxes with this values.

Comment: If you have a BackgroundWorker and using ReporProgress then post code.  Very slow and UI window seems to lose responsiveness are not the same.  The answer can only be as good as the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can always profile your application for memory leakages.
There are many things which can cause memory leaks in wpf applications.
Like event handling, dynamic resources, data binding etc..
Here are some of the links.

http://www.cplotts.com/2009/04/14/wpf-memory-leaks/

http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/learning-memory-management/WPF-silverlight-pitfalls

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b97a5f83-5394-430e-9a78-9d3a957e3537/dynamicresourcestaticresource-cause-memory-leaks?forum=wpf